# reorder table columns in Keen.io

Tags: tablecolumn, keen-io

I'm trying to figure out how to reorder the columns on a table built from an extraction query.  Changing the order in the 'property_names' field does not affect the column order displayed. I would like it to show 'subjectivity_range' column BEFORE 'text' column.

My  code is:

```
Keen.ready(function() {
var textq = new Keen.Query("extraction", {
     event_collection: source,
     timeframe: 'this_1_days',
     refresh_rate: "28000",
     property_names: ["subjectivity_range","text"],
     order_by: {'subjectivity_range':'result','direction':'DESC'},
     timezone:"US/Eastern"
    });
     .type('table')
     .title('Subjectivity examples')
     .prepare();

  client.run(textq, function(err, res) {
      textchart
      .data(res)
      .parseRequest(this)
      .render();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/keen/keen-dataviz.js#extraction-table-columns-order

```
/*
 dummy event model
 {
   user: {
     email: 'john@doe.com'
   },
   favourite_fruit: 'Avocado'
 }
*/

const chart = new KeenDataviz({
  container: '#some_container', // required
  table: {
    columns: ['favourite_fruit', 'user.email', 'keen.created_at'] // custom order of the columns
  }
});
```

You can use AZ Sorting, for example - descending:

```
   chartElement
     .data(responseFromApi)
     .sortGroups('desc')
     .render();
```